# Store object for future use (On Restarting Program)

Tags: c++, vector, std

I am implementing something similar to a neural network in C++. After learning I am left with a network with specific weights and inter connections between int nodes. Is there some way I can store this learned network for future use ?

The only way I can think of is to create a program that goes through each node , stores the weights and connections into a file and then recreate the network when I want to use it. I plan on doing this , but I wanted to know if there might be a better solution ?

What I mean is to  create a network on the heap , "learn" , and then store it as a file . So that I will be able to use this network that I learned later on , without going through the learning process.

The class that I want to store , has a std::vector of std::tuple which contains pointers and a float. 
Also this class that I want to store is composed of other class.

Comment: You will need to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data (into a stream of bytes) and write it somewhere (disk storage, network, print on paper, etc...). [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) can make this process less painful. There are also tons of machine learning frameworks and libs that probably handle all those mundane tasks for you.

Comment: Or using a database, and, and , and ... Way too broad question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What details should I add ?

Comment: @Drop This is part of research , what this does is a bit different from the commonly used neural networks. It seems boost::serialization will help me out. Any good tutorials you found more helpful than google ?

Comment: Instead of doing serialization in the general sense (i.e. enabling persistance of objects) which can be rather nontrivial, it might be ok for you to put all weights/coefficients into a single vector and store/load this vector in/from a file.

Comment: @nnrales Check out my link above. This is official documentation, including tutorials.

Comment: @nnrales There's not much point about more details, unless you're asking for specific code and specific problems you're stuck with. But you're asking for solutions available which is simply too broad and thus off-topic on [SO].

Comment: @Drop okay. Thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay. Thanks

Comment: @Drop One more thing. I use pointers extensively in the program. Will this have some effect while using boost::serialization ?

Comment: @nnrales Yes, this will seriously affect serialization, since serialized pointer values cannot be restored meaningfully from a saved file, database or whatever.

Comment: Yes, additionally to @πάντα ῥεῖ 's comment: `boost::serialization` have some instruments to facilitate serialization of pointers, but it's still more difficult and error-prone than serializing PODs or containers. You might optimize data layout for serialization (like tobi303 proposed), however it could imply redesign, increased code complexity and could probably change performance characteristics of your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could store it in a boost property tree (which can write itself to xml or json).

The example below assumes that you first convert the pointers into indices. That is; I assume each node has a number, and a *pointer* is then just another index pointing to that node.

I do agree with the many commenters suggesting to check out boost serialization (especially regarding the pointers), but for the problem you described, and for small data, this is going to work well. 
As it stands, it writes about 25000 nodes/second (only), and the file size is about 15MB for 1e4 nodes.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    using Node = std::tuple<double, size_t, size_t>;
    std::vector<Node> nodes;

    // example filling
    nodes.emplace_back(0.1, 1, 1);
    nodes.emplace_back(1.1, 2, 1);
    nodes.emplace_back(2.1, 1, 3);
    nodes.emplace_back(3.1, 0, 2);

    ptree pt_nodes;

    for (auto i = size_t(0); i < nodes.size() ; ++i) {
        const auto& node = nodes[i];
        ptree pt_node;
        pt_node.put("id", i);
        pt_node.put("w0", std::get<0>(node));
        pt_node.put("ptrA", std::get<1>(node));
        pt_node.put("ptrB", std::get<2>(node));
        pt_nodes.push_back(std::make_pair("node"+std::to_string(i), pt_node));
    }

    ptree pt_all;
    pt_all.add_child("nodes", pt_nodes);
    write_json("test1.json", pt_all);
```

The results are like this:

```
 {
    "nodes":
    {
        "node0":
        {
            "id": "0",
            "w0": "0.1",
            "ptrA": "1",
            "ptrB": "1"
        },
        "node1":
        {
            "id": "1",
            "w0": "1.1",
            "ptrA": "2",
            "ptrB": "1"
        },
        "node2":
        {
            "id": "2",
            "w0": "2.1",
            "ptrA": "1",
            "ptrB": "3"
        },
        "node3":
        {
            "id": "3",
            "w0": "3.1",
            "ptrA": "0",
            "ptrB": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Reading it back into a vector:

```
ptree pt_in;
read_json("test1.json", pt_in);
const auto pt_in_nodes = pt_in.get_child("nodes");
std::vector<Node> in_nodes(pt_in_nodes.size(), {});

for (const auto iter : pt_in_nodes)
{
    const auto ind = iter.second.get<size_t>("id");
    const auto w0 = iter.second.get<double>("w0");
    const auto ptrA= iter.second.get<size_t>("ptrA");
    const auto ptrB= iter.second.get<size_t>("ptrB");
    //std::cout << "id: " << ind << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "w0: " << w0 << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "ptrA: " << w1<< std::endl;
    //std::cout << "ptrB: " << ptr << std::endl;
    in_nodes.at(ind) = std::make_tuple(w0,ptrA,ptrB);
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend boost::serialization as the way to go , or it what you are suggesting better or easier ?

Comment: Storing data in text format is a good option when you are going to read or edit resulting output manually. However it is much slower and usually takes much more space. Depends on your data size of course. Machine learning usually implies giant data sets

Comment: Yes, but if it's giant data, then there's probably some infrastructure around this already.

Comment: @Drop Yes I am worried about this too , but since I am using pointers in the program , storing it as text is the only solution right ? Also as Johan assumes , I do have an id for each node if it helps you. You mentioned serialization had some ways of dealing with pointers. Could you give a bit more detail on this ?

Comment: @JohanLundberg No, I have no infrastructure around. I am a lowly undergrad.

Comment: @nnrales Check out `boost::serialization` docs, there is a section called ["Pointers"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#pointeroperators). No matter what format you are writing to, you will need to handle pointers.